# Run wp cli commands with cron job

Tags: wordpress, cron, wp-cli

Is it possbile to run WP cli commands with a cron job? Because I'm setting up a demo site, and want the site to be reset every 12 hour. And i thought that with wp cli, i can reset the installation. Import a file with the right content and so on.

Or do you guys have any better idea how to do this?

Comment: Can you configure wp_schedule_event() https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event for youк needs?

Comment: I also remember I read about http://wp-cli.org/commands/cron/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Here's a line from my `crontab` file.  (You can edit it by running `crontab -e`)

`*/10 * * * * /var/www/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/bin/wp --path=/var/www/ update-credits`

This runs my WP-CLI command `update-credits` every 10 minutes.

NOTE: I'm using WP-CLI as a Composer dependency in that website.  The path to your `wp` binary may vary.

Comment: Using full path to `wp` binary file is the key. It works in my case. Using only `wp` will fail.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.

Assuming you already have WP-CLI installed in your server, you could use something like the below line in your `/etc/crontab` file:

```
0 */12 * * * www-data wp --path=/var/www/yoursite.com db reset
```