# wp cli with crontab

Tags: linux, wordpress, cron, wp-cli

am trying to execute wp cli from crontab

i have done the following

first i create .sh file contain the following:

```html
   #!/bin/bash
   declare -a sites=('/home2/musite/public_html' )
   for site in "${sites[@]}";
   do
   /usr/local/bin/wp --path=$site --skip-plugins=wp-fastest-cache cron event run -  -all 
done
```

i tried to run the sh manually and it's run correct but when am scheduling the file to be run automatically through crontab i got the following error:

PHP Warning:  array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php on line 622
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

**Warning**:  array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in **phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php** on line **622**
 PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/WP_CLI/Configurator.php on line 132 
**Warning**:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in **phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/WP_CLI/Configurator.php** on line **132**
 PHP Warning:  proc_open(): Descriptor item must be either an array or a File-Handle in phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/commands/help.php on line 111 
**Warning**:  proc_open(): Descriptor item must be either an array or a File-Handle in **phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/commands/help.php** on line **111**
 PHP Warning:  proc_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/commands/help.php on line 111 
**Warning**:  proc_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in **phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/commands/help.php** on line **111**

can you please help me with i mad a lot of research but am still can't figure out why this happening.

thanks

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: yes i did it as follow:

 /usr/local/bin/php  /usr/local/bin/wp --skip-plugins=`cat /home2/mysite/public_html/skipplugins.txt`  cron event run --all --path=/home2/mysite/public_html/

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38766046/run-wp-cli-commands-with-cron-job

Answer (score 0):

the solution to run the wp-cli from crontab as follow:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/bin/wp --skip-plugins=cat /home2/mysite/public_html/skipplugins.txt cron event run --all --path=/home2/mysite/public_html
```

Comment: `--due-now` is usually better than `--all` just fyi.