# How to have wp-cli commands work in a bash script from cron

Tags: wordpress, bash, wp-cli

I have a bash script with various WP-CLI commands to run a backup, check & optimize db tables, run a security vulnerability check, check available core, plugin, and theme updates, and then email the report to me.

If I run this script from the command line, it works perfectly. However, if I schedule a cronjob, the script runs, but the output for all WP commands are as such:

> /usr/local/bin/dev-maintenance-check.bash: line 70: wp: command not found

I've tried various different cron job formats to no avail. This is the current cronjob:

```
0 1 * * 0,3 bash /usr/local/bin/dev-maintenance-check.bash
```

My WP-cli installation is at usr/local/bin/wp. Again, if I run "bash /usr/local/bin/dev-maintenance-check.bash" in the command line, that works.

To me, it sounds like the wp-cli needs to be called in the script. I feel confident that I've exhausted my search on Google on the wp-cli docs. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40452265/wp-cli-with-crontab

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/654785/wp-cli-doesnt-run-from-cronjob

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38766046/run-wp-cli-commands-with-cron-job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As your script is a shell script (/bin/sh), then your PATH entries in
>   .bashrc will not be read as that is for the bash (/bin/bash)
>   interactive shell.
>
> To make your PATH entries available to /bin/sh scripts run by a
>   specific user, add the PATH entry to the .profile file in that users
>   home directory.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163126/72176

---

So, the interesting part is not your crontab, but your script. Simply call the absolute or relative location to `wp` or fix it as suggested above and it should work.

Absolute:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /var/www/wordpress
/usr/local/bin/wp cache flush
```

Relative (WP-CLI installed as local Composer dependency):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /var/www/wordpress
vendor/bin/wp cache flush
```

Comment: It is a good idea to set the PATH variable so cron can find the commands I want to run. I have to put the following line at the beginning of crontab file. <code>PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin</code> <br />
The question is: How can I verify that this is the right path I have to use?